# PHP service to C#

Tags: c#, php, service

in php i post a request like

```
$.post("/service.php?cat=c1", {
     group: $this.attr('href'),
})
```

where group -> #$!/mycat/year,2012

now i want to do same request in c#

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( url);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
      result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I tried

```
String url = domain + "./service.php?cat=c1&group=%22#$!/mycat/year,2012%22";
```

and

```
String url = domain + "./service.php?cat=c1&group=mycat&year=2012";
```

but "message" always returns empty 
What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you show your php code?

Comment: I see no reference to "message"... ?

Comment: sorry, not "message", it is "result"

Comment: Your PHP code may be checking for group to be sent via `$_POST`. In your C# code its being passed via `$_GET`

Comment: I would use Fiddler to monitor the request that the php code generates and the request that this c# program generates, and then compare the two

Comment: I think you're confused ... The "PHP" example you gave is actually javascript... So, you're calling a PHP page from JS and now you want to replace the PHP with c#? Or you're replacing the Javascript and want to call the same PHP page from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `WebClient` class, as this is easier to use.

Pass in the values as `NameValueCollection` object

```
    var client = new WebClient();


var nameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("cat=c1&group=mycat&year=2012");

var response = client.UploadValues(domain + "/service.php","POST",nameValueCollection);


  var responseStr = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
```